# Using Solicore flexible batteries as replacement of CR2032

Tags: batteries, bluetooth-low-energy

A device that I am using ([Gimbal iBeacon series 10](https://gimbal.com/doc/proximity_overview.html#beacons)) uses 1 CR2032 battery that lasts for 3 months.
I am trying to find out if I can replace it with a flexible unit from Solicore.

- [CR2032 spec from Energizer](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/cr2032.pdf)
- [Solicore flexible batteries spec](http://www.solicore.com/product-matrix.asp)

Questions:

1. Which Solicore battery (if any) can I use as replacement of CR2032
2. If it can be replaced. How many of the Solicore batteries do I have to have to extend the life to 1 year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would take about 100 Solicore batteries to last a year.

The CR2032 is around 240mAh, the Solicore is 10-14mAh. To equal a CR2032 with the high power 14mAh batteries:
$$
\frac{240}{14} = 17.15 
$$
Multiply that by 4 for a year, so 68.6 batteries.

For the 10mAh ones it's 
$$
\frac{240}{10} \times 4  = 24 \times 4 = 96
$$.

They may be thin, but are they 100x thinner than a single CR2032?

And that's not even mentioning the minuscule current they can provide...